# Квадратики вместо русских букв

Tags: кодировка, php

Здравствуйте! У меня на сайте отображаются квадратики вместо некоторых русских букв. Как исправить эту проблему? Кодировка - UTF8. База тоже в кодировке utf8. Додскажите, как решить эту проблему!

Comment: Вместо НЕКОТОРЫХ русских букв? Каких именно?

Comment: @zhenyab такое бывает, как ни странно) обычно это буквы "Й", "Ф", и иже с ними.

Comment: сбросьте хотя бы ссылку на сайт

Answer (score 0):

кодировку файла выставь utf8

Answer (score 0):

В mysql есть несколько типов UTF-8 кодировок. И даже файл может быть в UTF-8 с/без BOM. Все это может влиять на отображение. Для начала, советую посмотреть, где возникает проблема - в текстах, содержащихся в файлах. или в текстах из БД. Откройте БД через phpmyadmin, посмотрите в какой кодировке именно тот текст, в котором есть ошибка. На основе этого уже можно будет сделать какие-то выводы.